# Which one is correct? why? if they both are correct, what's the difference in terms of meaning?

Tags: absolute-clauses

> 1- Once you reach the top, *perhaps no one **seeing** you*, you’ll be able to
>   see top of the world. Occasionally, life means hardworking for a dream
>   not seen by anyone other than you.

Or

> 2-Once you reach the top, *perhaps no one **sees** you*, you’ll be able to see top of the world. Occasionally, life means hardworking for a dream not seen by anyone other than you.

P.S. Suppose that *italic* one is adverbial phrase. I consider the first one to be correct because of Absolute clause being used there. But I am not sure about its relevance.

Comment: The construction you have chosen is very awkward in English. I suggest: "Once you reach the top, _perhaps seen by no-one,_..."

Comment: This is a clause that cries out for the use of the passive voice, for example **perhaps unseen by anyone**

Comment: Does the phrase "perhaps unseen by anyone" or " perhaps seen by no-one" refers "you" or "the top" in your sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think either really work. You are adding a qualifying idea into the "reach the top ... you'll be able to see", but as currently expressed it's ambiguous. Do you mean that once you are at the top you may not be seen, or do you mean that no one sees you in the process of making it to the top.

Either expression could have either meaning but

> no one seeing you

has more of the flavour of seeing the process of getting to the top

> no one sees you

has more of the flavour of being seen once at the top.

I would want to phrase this in a way that makes the intent clear

> Once you reach the top, even though now maybe no one can see you, you’ll be able to see top of the world. Occasionally, life means hardworking for a dream not seen by anyone other than you.

explicitly saying what the observer can (or rather cannot) see

> Once you reach the top, even though no one saw your climb, you’ll be able to see top of the world. Occasionally, life means hardworking for a dream not seen by anyone other than you.